# Do null pointer deference and uninitialized memory belong to memory corruption

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

In wikipedia, [memory corruption](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) is defined as follows:

> Memory corruption occurs in a computer program when the contents of a
>   memory location are unintentionally modified due to programming
>   errors; this is termed violating memory safety.

But in the subsequent description, null pointer dereference and uninitialized memory are considered memory corruption.

I'm a little confused. Null pointer dereference and uninitialized memory do not unintentionally modify the contents of a memory location. Why are they regarded as memory corruption?

Comment: Null pointer deference is _undefined behavior_ (UB), not unintentional modification of a memory location.  Anything may happen including memory corruption.

Comment: So memory _corruption_ is unintended modification. Dereferencing a null pointer so is not corruption. But it will get you a run-time error. Uninitialized memory is either intentional (it will get values later), or an error and when used, may cause run-time errors, but in itself is not memory corruption.

Comment: According to your comments, I think null pointer deference cannot be regarded as memory corruption. Am I right?

Comment: @Haijun - Correct. It's a constraint violation. A program that does that is ill-formed according to the C language specification.

Comment: NPE is not itself memory corruption, the side effect is, well, anything, and one of them is memory corruption. _Hint: Check your credit card usage after you run a program causing UB_.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie  "Dereferencing a null pointer ...  will get you a run-time error." is not specified by C, yet a possible outcome of UB. §6.5.3.2 4

Comment: @StoryTeller How can it be a constraint violation, when most often it is a run-time bug? Constraint violation of what?

Comment: Interestingly, some micro controllers can be reset by setting the instruction pointer to address 0 - UB, sure, but this is often achieved by calling a null function pointer...

Comment: An (attempted) null pointer dereference is certainly a memory-related programming issue, but it is not reasonable to characterize it as memory corruption.  However, it might either *result from* or *produce* memory corruption.

Comment: @Lundin - The standard defines a constraint as [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#3.8), which I read to mean that semnatic sections can introduce constraints as well, albeit not necessarily ones a compiler can catch. The semantic behavior of unary `*` is [this](http://port70.net/~nsz/c/c11/n1570.html#6.5.3.2p4). So I see it as a constraint violation.

Comment: @StoryTeller Given the context "syntactic or semantic", the definition of "Contraints" likely just refer to "semantic" as "logical rules", rather than "Semantics" as the chapter format of the standard. A constraint is a requirement which I believe can always be checked statically. All the text below "constraints" as well as "semantics" is however normative, so a violation of a constraint is by no means more severe than a violation of the semantics.

Comment: @anatolyg [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_corruption) "Memory corruption errors can be broadly classified into four categories:" /--/ "Using none-owned memory: It is common to use pointers to access and modify memory. If such a pointer is a null pointer, dangling pointer..."

Comment: memory corruption even sometimes caused my hardware also.

Answer (score 4):

"Memory corruption" is not a formal term, so it is not very meaningful to go look for a formal definition. Also, Wikipedia is not necessarily a canonical source of information.

A null pointer access may or may not lead to memory corruption. Mostly this depends on if the system allows writes to address 0 or not<sup>1)</sup>.

Similarly, using an uninitialized or "dangling" pointer that points at any random location can cause any kind of behavior, including memory corruption.

These all fall under the formal term *undefined behavior*, which means that anything can happen should you invoke such behavior.

---

<sup>1)</sup> In theory, the C language forbids the compiler to give a null pointer an address that might correspond to a real address on the target. In practice, compilers most often don't do this but just use the address zero. Which is a valid address on many microcontroller systems or other such computers that allow direct access to physical memory.

Answer (score 0):

Dereferencing a null pointer reference cannot corrupt memory unless the first page is mapped to the process address space.

Most operating systems do not map this page by default (although many allow the user to map it if they so choose).

Because a null pointer will reference nothing, you cannot corrupt anything by accessing it.

The pointer itself may be corrupted if it has a null (or any other invalid value).